# log out/in because of google-chrome-stable package update?

Tags: linux, fedora, chrome

After i configured my Fedora 14 to do auto updates:

```
gconftool-2 -t string -s /apps/gnome-packagekit/update-icon/auto_update all
gconftool-2 -t integer -s /apps/gnome-packagekit/update-icon/frequency_get_updates 3600
gconftool-2 -t bool -s /apps/gnome-packagekit/update-icon/notify_available 0
gconftool-2 -t bool -s /apps/gnome-packagekit/update-icon/notify_complete 0
gconftool-2 -t bool -s /apps/gnome-packagekit/update-icon/notify_critical 0
gconftool-2 -t bool -s /apps/gnome-packagekit/update-icon/notify_update_complete_restart 0
gconftool-2 -t bool -s /apps/gnome-packagekit/update-icon/notify_update_started 0
```

I get this funny [message](http://img851.imageshack.us/img851/2673/updatez.png).

Why do i have to log out/in because of the google-chrome-stable package has been updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PackageKit has the ability to notify when an Application, Session or the System needs to be restarted.  For some reason, the Google Chrome package is causing PackageKit to notify you that your login session needs to be restarted.  I think that the way PackageKit manages this kind of thing is a worst-case scenario, so it assumes that the whole session needs to be restarted, not just the application.  It might be worth submitting a bug report to Google about it.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that it's a funny message. You don't really have to log out and log in again, but you should make sure that the program and anything using any shared libraries are restarted.

I think the message was just chosen because logging out and in again is the most simple way to make sure that happens for users who don't know what they're doing. (For some things, like system libraries, it'll tell you to reboot.)